# How do I extract emails from dictionary in python as key value pair?

Tags: python, python-3.x

From the following dictionary  structure, how do I extract and print email addresses? E.g. I want to see 'smauel.david@gmail' 4, 'sdusa@yahoo.com' 1, etc.

```
dict_items([('10:04:14', 1), ('3', 6), ('Thu', 6), ('19:51:21', 1),
('2008',27),  ('From', 27), ('11:35:08', 1), ('5', 1),
('sntp@hotmail.com', 3), ('Jan', 27), ('15:46:24', 1), ('14:50:18',
1),  ('11:37:30', 1), ('18:10:48', 1), ('17:07:00', 1), ('09:05:31',
1),  ('10:38:42', 1), ('sdusa@yahoo.com', 1),
('samuel.david@gmail.com', 4) ])
```

Comment: This community rocks. Great people, always willing to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**dict comprehensions**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/)

```
d = dict([('10:04:14', 1), ('3', 6), ('Thu', 6), ('19:51:21', 1),('2008',27),  ('From', 27), ('11:35:08', 1), ('5', 1),('sntp@hotmail.com', 3), ('Jan', 27), ('15:46:24', 1), ('14:50:18',1),  ('11:37:30', 1), ('18:10:48', 1), ('17:07:00', 1), ('09:05:31',1),  ('10:38:42', 1), ('sdusa@yahoo.com', 1),('samuel.david@gmail.com', 4) ])

{email:val for email, val in d.items() if '@' in email }
```

**output:**

```
 {'sdusa@yahoo.com': 1, 'samuel.david@gmail.com': 4, 'sntp@hotmail.com': 3}
```

Comment: Brilliant, short and simple. It worked. I love this community of developers and trust their expertise. It was a brain freeze and just couldn't think. You saved my lot of time. I hope to stay in touch for professional advice. A million thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the keys, and grab only those that contain `@` (assuming that all your keys are either hours or email addresses):

```
d = dict([('10:04:14', 1), ('3', 6), ('Thu', 6), ('19:51:21', 1), ('2008',27),  ('From', 27), ('11:35:08', 1), ('5', 1), ('sntp@hotmail.com', 3), ('Jan', 27), ('15:46:24', 1), ('14:50:18', 1),  ('11:37:30', 1), ('18:10:48', 1), ('17:07:00', 1), ('09:05:31', 1),  ('10:38:42', 1), ('sdusa@yahoo.com', 1), ('samuel.david@gmail.com', 4) ])

for key in d:
    if "@" in key:
        print(key)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
sntp@hotmail.com
samuel.david@gmail.com
sdusa@yahoo.com
```

Comment: Brilliant, short and simple. It worked. I love this community of developers and trust their expertise. It was a brain freeze and just couldn't think. You saved my lot of time. I hope to stay in touch for professional advice. A million thanks.

Comment: @Samuel are you a bot ? :)

Comment: Yes indeed now I am back on track. Thanks again. Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming:

```
>>> d=dict([('10:04:14', 1), ('3', 6), ('Thu', 6), ('19:51:21', 1),
... ('2008',27),  ('From', 27), ('11:35:08', 1), ('5', 1),
... ('sntp@hotmail.com', 3), ('Jan', 27), ('15:46:24', 1), ('14:50:18',
... 1),  ('11:37:30', 1), ('18:10:48', 1), ('17:07:00', 1), ('09:05:31',
... 1),  ('10:38:42', 1), ('sdusa@yahoo.com', 1),
... ('samuel.david@gmail.com', 4) ])
```

If the address are of the type you show, you can use `filter` on the keys:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda s: '@' in s, d.keys()))
['sdusa@yahoo.com', 'samuel.david@gmail.com', 'sntp@hotmail.com']
```

If, however, you might have more complete strings representing the RFC822 email address of `'Comment' <address>` type (or a mixture) you might want to use [email.utils.parseaddr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parseaddr) to separate the comment (or real name) from the actual address:

```
>>> from email.utils import parseaddr
>>> parseaddr('"Santa" <Santa@np.org>')
('Santa', 'Santa@np.org')
```

So then:

```
>>> d=dict([('10:04:14', 1), ('3', 6), ('Thu', 6), ('19:51:21', 1),
... ('2008',27),  ('From', 27), ('11:35:08', 1), ('5', 1),
... ('sntp@hotmail.com', 3), ('Jan', 27), ('15:46:24', 1), ('14:50:18',
... 1),  ('11:37:30', 1), ('18:10:48', 1), ('17:07:00', 1), ('09:05:31',
... 1),  ('10:38:42', 1), ('sdusa@yahoo.com', 1),
... ('"Sammy Davis, Jr." <samuel.david@gmail.com>', 4) ])
>>> 
>>> from email.utils import parseaddr
>>> [parseaddr(s)[1] for s in d.keys() if '@' in parseaddr(s)[1]]
['sntp@hotmail.com', 'samuel.david@gmail.com', 'sdusa@yahoo.com']
```

Note: `parseaddr` Only separates the parts of a valid but complete RFC822 address; it does not validate that it is a real address.

Comment: Brilliant, short and simple. It worked. I love this community of developers and trust their expertise. It was a brain freeze and just couldn't think. You saved my lot of time. I hope to stay in touch for professional advice. A million thanks. This was also an alternate solution and it worked fine as well. I learned new things.